# git rebase on a feature branch already pushed to remote

Tags: git, rebase

Suppose I have  feature branch locally, FB. FB has diverged from master at commit, say CC. FB  has several commits more, say FBC1,FBC2.FB is pushed to remote repository, and then merged into master. So remote master has FBC1,FBC2, and then few more commits prior and after.

Now if I pull remote commits to my local, so that my local master is now having CC-MC1-MC2-FBC1-FBC2-MC3-MC4, while FB has CC-FBC1-FBC2. So both master and FB have commits FBC1,FBC2.

Now if I rebase master on FB, then what would be behaviour?

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see?

Comment: I think nothing will happen, because, if I understood correctly, FB is already an ancestor of master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:** It will do what rebase does, which is replay all (non-merge) commits that are in the source branch but not in the target branch, on top of the target branch.

First let's consider the opposite of what you asked: What if we rebase `FB` onto `master`? Every commit in `FB` is already in `master`, so it will place 0 commits on top of `master`. The result is `FB` will be reset to look exactly like `master`.

Now for your question, if we rebase `master` onto `FB`, every (non-merge) commit that is on `master` but not also in `FB`, will be replayed on top of `FB`. Your example only shows merge commits, but presumably those merge commits before and after the merge commit for branch `FB` brought in some other commits with the merge? In that case, all of those commits would be replayed without their corresponding merge commits and the graph would be modified to become linear after commit FB2. (This assumes there are no conflicts and the rebase succeeds.)

To see which commits would be replayed and subsequently "rearranged" on `master`, you can run this command:

`git log FB..master --no-merges`

That shows all the commits in `master` that aren't in `FB`, minus the merge commits.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would do anything because when you try to rebase a branch, git will try to find the last common ancestor between the branches involved... and at that point that revision is the tip of FB so git sees that there's nothing to rebase.